# Does Live Mesh exclude .aspx/.ascx files?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, live-mesh

I'm tired of zipping up my ASP.net MVC project all the time, so I tried to connect the entire project folder to Live Mesh, so I could work on it both at home and at the office. It seemed to work, but it turns out all the views are excluded and replaced with .wlx counterparts.

Is this a known limitation of Mesh? Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: I really wouldn't use LiveMesh to move projects between computers - it's difficult to guarantee that you're working on the right version, and conflicts are annoying to resolve. You're really best off using some kind of source control. For personal projects, you can almost certainly get hosted SVN for nothing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69384/opinion-of-hosted-svn-providers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.wlx is a temporary extension that indicates that a file is a placeholder for a file that hasn't been transferred yet.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. I tried to give it enough time to upload, but maybe I wasn't patient enough. Download has been given plenty of time, though.

Comment: Its kind of hard to see what its doing - I've seen it sync instantly and I've had cases where it seems, erm, "reluctant" and works itself out when you're not looking.

Answer (score 0):

I agree live mesh appears to still be very much in beta. Some of my files are still .wlx 10 hours later and nothing appears to be syncing. However, it is a great program and I look forwward to the next update. It makes my life much easier since I run Windows inside VMWare.